# WiFiClient::connected() not working

Tags: esp8266, wifi, esp32

I use an ESP32 to open an access point and listen for TCP connections over a WiFiServer object.

When I get a client on the server I want to know when it has disconnected.

Currently I have a simple piece of code on both the client and the server side. I connect using a TcpClient in C#.

When I call `client.close()` on the client side, the `client.connected()` loop on the server just continues forever.

Here is the ESP code:

```cpp
void setup()
{
   WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);

   WiFi.softAP("test");

   WiFi.softAPConfig(IPAddress(192, 168, 4, 1), IPAddress(192, 168, 4, 1), IPAddress(255, 255, 255, 0));

   Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

   server.begin();
}

void loop()
{
    while (!client)
    {
        client = server.available();

        delay(10);
    }

    while (client.connected())
    {
        Serial.println("ok");

        delay(1000);

        client.read();
    }
}
```

C# code:

```cpp
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     TcpClient client = new TcpClient("192.168.4.1", 222);

     client.Close();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE.  I don't really see a question here.  I see a statement of the problem but no attempts at resolution nor a question about why such an attempted fix didn't work.    I recommend you take the tour at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.  Perhaps you can flesh it out enough to prevent closure of this one.  Or, if it does get closed, perhaps you can repost it with the elements necessary to present a question that can attract useful answers.

Comment: @SDsolar I'm absolutely aware on how to write on this site, because I'm on stackoverflow as well. Furthermore my question is clear when you read the title and the second line. I'm explaining my intention there and with a little bit of think you can guess that I need help with this function. Instead of writng pointless comments spend the time writing some answers.

Comment: I just don't see a question here, that's all.  This is a Q&A site.  Without one you can't have the other.   I voted to leave this one open when it came up in review, thinking a little nudge was all you needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in a previous version of the library as mentioned on 
https://github.com/bportaluri/WiFiEsp/issues/14

You can alternatively use WiFi.softAPgetStationNum() to get the count of stations connected to the AP interface.

Comment: WiFiEsp isn't the library I'm using, is it? Unfortunately `WiFi.softAPgetStationNum()` does't help me, because I need to know when the socket has disconnected and not a Station.

Comment: Whether you're using the WiFiEsp library is not a question I know the answer to.

Comment: I've seen the client.connected() function in WiFiEsp only

Comment: This one's `WiFiEspClient::connected()` and not `WiFiClient::connected()`

Answer (score 1):

**My actual answer**

You can try to inquire `client.status()` as a workaround. When no one is connected it should return 0.

**Context**

What are you building on? I tried to reproduce your problem but everything works as expected, the serial stops printing "ok" when I disconnect.

Also, what libraries are you using exactly? I included `ESP8266WiFi.h` and `WiFiClient.h`.

I used platformio v3.4 on an ESP8266-01 module and a simple Android netcat app as client.

Comment: `ESP8266WiFi.h` is for an ESP8266 which is the wrong plattform, I have an ESP32 Development Board. I included `#include <WiFi.h>`.